# Simplify my markup for custom responsive menu (No Bootstrap!)

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've built a custom responsive menu with the hamburger icon, but without Bootstrap - I don't want to use Bootstrap.

The problem is that I'd like to use simple markup to accomplish this but I had to add a separate nav that I show/hide with media queries and I know there's got to be a better way but I'm not sure how.

The Bootstrap model does have a separate nav with collapse class but shouldn't I be able to do this simply using one nav?

Here is the JS Fiddle for what I've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/zbu7ahmb/10/

As I see it, I shouldn't need this much markup to accomplish what I want. I don't want this menu-collapsed nav bar:

```
<div id="header" class="inline-container max-width space-between">
<div>
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
</div>

<nav class="menu inline-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-btn">
            <button id="my_btn" class="nav-link btn-link">Link 1</button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="section">Section 1</li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
                <li class="section row">Section 2</li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-btn">
            <button class="nav-link btn-link">Link 2</button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="menu-collapsed">
    <div class="container nav-link" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="section"><h3>Link 1</h3></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
        <li class="section row"><h3>Link 2</h3></li>
        <li>Section 1</li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
        <li class="row">Section 2</li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Shouldn't I be able to simply use 1 navigation bar like this:

```
<div id="header" class="inline-container max-width space-between">
<div>
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
</div>

<nav class="menu inline-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-btn">
            <button id="my_btn" class="nav-link btn-link">Link 1</button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="section">Section 1</li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
                <li class="section row">Section 2</li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-btn">
            <button class="nav-link btn-link">Link 2</button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Lastly, notice that I had to give my "menu-collapsed sub-menu" a width of 91% to get it to stretch across ...but it's still a little off. What's the best way to solve this?

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks for any input!

Comment: you can keep only one, but you have to add a bunch of media query CSS in order to change the syle of your menu in mobile.

Comment: In your fiddle you have different navigation for mobile resolutions compared to larger resolutions. Are you looking for a solution with the same navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one single menu, and you have to use the css media queries to change the styles of the menu items instead of show/hide the whole menu.

1. Create your html menu with the structure you need.
2. Decide what will be your default view. I prefer to design "Mobile First", because you usually have more limitations, so when you later design the desktop view your have more options and space, and for me is easier to adapt.
3. Create the css styles in your CSS file for the default view you've decided. Make the menu look and behave like you want in that view.
4. Once you have that done and working, it's time to create the CSS Media Queries for the rest of the views. Put that rules after all the rules you've created for your default view. Now you're not changing the whole menu, you're just styling your menu and menu elements to adapt to the new distribution and look. In most cases you'll use the viewport width as the parameter for the css media queries. If your default style is for mobile, you can add css media queries to change the menu once you reach an specific width. For example...

   ```
   nav.menu { position: absolute; z-index: 10; width: 100%; background-color: #1c8db0; display: none; }
   nav.menu li.nav-btn { width: 100; }
   nav.menu li.nav-btn ul li { width: 100; }
   /* Your default styles for "mobile" here */

   @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
       nav.menu { position: relative; z-index: 0; width: auto; display: block; }
       nav.menu li.nav-btn { width: 250px; }
       nav.menu li.nav-btn ul li { width: 250px; }
       /* Modify and add styles when the viewport is at least 1024px */
   }

   @media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
       nav.menu li.nav-btn { width: 350px; }
       nav.menu li.nav-btn ul li { width: 350px; }
       /* Modify and add styles when the viewport is at least 1280px */
   }
   ```

   Just play with the styles to adapt the menu, but notice that working in this way you're changing the default styles you've created, so if you need to change one style for the new width you have to overwrite it.
5. And what about "The Hamburger Button"? Create it and put it in the position that has to be for the mobile view. Then, just hide it using the same media queries.

This is just a quick description of my process for creating responsive menus. I don't like having different menus, because is usually harder to maintain. The same menu, but just change how it looks.

I hope it helps.